# Can't find the correct variable change for this double integral, help?

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, linear-transformations, change-of-variable

[image]

Hello friends!

I've tried using the typical variable change $u = x+y$ and $v = x-y$
but this gives you a determinant of 1/2, which doesn't let you prove the equality.

PD: For those that can't read spanish the picture says: find $D \epsilon R^2$ so that the equation is true for every pair of continuous functions $f$ and $g$

Comment: You've got the right change of variable; the question is "If $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ is the domain of integration on the right, what's the domain $D$ of integration on the left?"

Comment: Well, with that change of variables D would be the "diamond" of vertices (0,0), (1,1), (1/2, -1/2), (1/2, 1/2). But that still doesn't give an answer to how to remove the 1/2 factor that would appear on the right side of the equation

Comment: What's the area of that diamond?

Comment: It just cannot be done.